# How to create JavaFX Transition with Equally-Timed Elements?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm experimenting with JavaFX and animations, especially `PathTransition`. I'm creating a simple program that makes a ball "bounce," without using the `QuadCurveTo` class. Here is my code so far:

```
Ellipse ball = new Ellipse(375, 250, 10, 10);
root.getChildren().add(ball);

Path path = new Path();
path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(375, 500));

int posX = 375;
int posY = 500;
int changeX = 10;
int changeY = 50;
int gravity = 10; // approximate in m/s^2
int sec = 0;

for(; posY<=500; sec++, posX-=changeX, posY-=changeY, changeY-=gravity)
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(posX, posY));
    // How do I equally space these elements?

PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(sec*1000));
pathTransition.setNode(ball);
pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
pathTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
pathTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
pathTransition.setPath(path);
pathTransition.play();
```

I have the `for` loop running through a quadratic sequence, and the ball moves in the correct motion (a curved path).

However, I want it to move slower at the top of the curve (vertex) because it is moving less distance (as `changeY`, the vertical increment variable, is decreasing as the loop goes on) to simulate a more realistic curve. However, it is traveling in a linear speed throughout the full time.

Is there any way to make each of the elements equally spaced (throughout) time, so that this "bounce" would show correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use a timeline or transition at all for this. Use an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) and compute the new coordinates based on the elapsed time since the last frame.

Comment: @James_D Sorry, I'm new to JavaFX and don't know how that works. The JavaDocs is also a little confusing. Could you post an answer with an example or post a link to a working example? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use a timeline or transition at all for this. Use an AnimationTimer and compute the new coordinates based on the elapsed time since the last frame. The `AnimationTimer` has a `handle` method which is invoked once per rendering frame, taking a value that represents a timestamp in nanoseconds.

SSCCE (with elasticity added to the physics):

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BouncingBall extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Circle ball = new Circle(20, 80, 10);
        ball.setFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
        Pane pane = new Pane(ball);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            long lastUpdate = 0 ;
            double changeX = 0.1 ;
            double changeY = 0 ;
            double gravity = 10 ;
            double elasticity = 0.95 ;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if (lastUpdate == 0) {
                    lastUpdate = now ;
                    return ;
                }
                long elapsedNanos = now - lastUpdate;
                double elapsedSeconds = elapsedNanos / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                lastUpdate = now ;
                ball.setCenterX(ball.getCenterX() + changeX);
                if (ball.getCenterY() + changeY + ball.getRadius() >= pane.getHeight()) {
                    changeY = - changeY * elasticity;
                } else {
                    changeY = changeY + gravity * elapsedSeconds ;
                }
                ball.setCenterY(Math.min(ball.getCenterY() + changeY, pane.getHeight() - ball.getRadius()));
            }

        };

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps, especially with the SSCCE! If only the JavaFX tutorials had told me this earlier...