# How to provide custom tick/pulse generator for JavaFX 8 animation?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8, video-processing

By default JavaFX animations run against the system clock. What class controls that and how to replace it? I'm looking for a class that decided what time is it  and when a next frame occurs.

---

Why do I need this? I'm trying to use it in video processing, to add some animations. The problem is that a video has its own timeline and when frames are being processed they run faster than the real wall clock time. Is it at all possible to use JavaFX for non-UI purposes?

Comment: The code you are looking for will be buried very deep, is not public API, and is probably implemented in native code (at least on most common platforms). [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#JFXST788) gives a very high level overview of the way the architecture is defined. You can execute code on each frame rendering using an `AnimationTimer` (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463653/how-to-create-javafx-transition-with-equally-timed-elements/31464003#31464003). Not sure if that is what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

In `com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer` class there is MainLoop private class which generate pulse.

Some of `javafx.animation.Animation` constructors allow you to provide your own `AbstractMasterTimer`, however there are to test-only usage.