# How to resolve lag with javafx when adding button to root node

Tags: java, macos, javafx, macos-monterey

I'm trying to recreate Flappy Bird on javafx, but whenever the bird dies, the game freezes momentarily, before the gameover GUI appears. However, when I restart the game (without stopping the program) and die again, the same lag does not occur.

My question is, why does the game lag during the first gameover but not during subsequent gameovers? And how can I resolve this lag?

I think I pinpointed the source of the lag to when I add the button node to the root node:
When bird dies, the gameover GUIs (including restart button) added to the root node. When I didn't add the button, the game did not lag.

Btw, I'm using macOS Moneterey.

I've reproduced the same problem in a simplified version of my code below, except the lag occurs at the beginning. If you run it, you'll notice it takes a second or two for the nodes (which include a moving box and a restart button) to appear initially, but if you press the restart button, the nodes reappear smoothly. If you comment out the button node and run the program, you'll notice the lag does not occur at all.

```
public class Main extends Application{

    Group root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        game();
    }

    public void game(){
        root.getChildren().clear();

        Rectangle bird = new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.BLACK);
        bird.setX(0);
        root.getChildren().add(bird);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer(){

            @Override
            public void handle(long l) {
                bird.setX(bird.getX() + 1);
            }
        };

        timer.start();

        Button btn = new Button("Restart");
        btn.setLayoutX(200);
        btn.setLayoutY(200);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            timer.stop();
            game();
        });
    }

}
```

For those who would like to take a look at my actual project: https://github.com/ycz425/javafx-flappybird.git

Comment: `start((Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());` does not sit right. Try to structure your code without that line.

Comment: `start()` is supposed to be called when the entire application starts. It doesn’t make any sense to call it more than once. Can you refactor this example to something more realistic? That said: creating an entire scene from scratch and replacing the existing scene with it is likely to be an expensive operation. Why not just replace the scene’s root? Or, perhaps better, create the alternative root at startup instead of creating it on the fly.

Comment: It won’t make any difference, but why did you write `start((Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());` when simply `start(stage);` is completely equivalent? This is [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) in an extreme form. `(Node)event.getSource()` is necessarily the same as `btn`, and `btn.getScene()` is necessarily the same as `scene`, and `(Stage)scene.getWindow()` is necessarily the same as `stage`.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing much in your Application class.  The first four lines in start are fine, but everything after that belongs elsewhere.  Follow [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  The Application class should only be concerned with the [*application* lifecycle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html).  That is different than your game lifecycle as you can play multiple games within a single application lifecycle.

Comment: @James_D yes. That line of code was originally in another method that didn't take `Stage` as an argument. I copied and pasted bits of my program onto here so it slipped my mind. I also updated the code so that `start()` is only called at the beginning, and only the root is replaced, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Do not busy wait on the JavaFX application thread. Start the timer _after_ the stage is set; stop the timer _when_ motion ends. Also consider a suitable `Transition`.

Comment: Try remembering the property values/states of the original state and reset those values/states on "new game".

Comment: A related `AnimationTimer` example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464003/230513).